# React-native: Trying to print data dependent on data.child

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a set of data in firebase with child-node `"type" = [job, event]` and I want to print the data differently depending on which type it is.

[image: Here is the datastructure]

This is my code:

```
export default class mobilefomoapp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   var ref = firebase.database().ref('opportunities');

   this.state = {
      jobs : [],
      events : [],
   };
}

setJobs(){
 ref.orderByChild("Type").equalTo('job').on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  this.setState({
     jobs : snapshot,
   });
 });
}

render() {
    return (
    <Container>
     {this.state.jobs}
    </Container>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code?

Comment: It doesn't display anything. Tried console.log(this.state.jobs) and there was nothing stored there either @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Can you edit your code to show where you logged? And then also show the output you got from that logging?

Comment: Also: what does the `Container` component do with the `snapshot` that you give it?

Answer (score 0):

It works now! Seems the issue was that I was rendering an array of objects and not particular childs of each object. Thanks a lot for the prompt @Frank!

```
export default class mobilefomoapp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('opportunities');
    this.state = {
      jobs : [],
      events : [],
    };
  }

  SetJobs(){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('opportunities');
    ref.orderByChild("Type").equalTo('job').once('value').then(
      snapshot => {
        this.setState({
          jobs: snapshot.val(),
        });
      }
    )
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.SetJobs()
  }

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.jobs)
        return (
        <Container>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        {/* {this.state.jobs.Title} */}
        </Container>
      );
    }
}
```